# How to make parts of a json string bold in react native

Tags: html, css, json, react-native

I have a json file like this...

```
 {
    "key1": "key1",
    "value1": "I only want this part of the text to be bold",

    "key2": "key2",
    "value2": "I don't want any text here to be bold"
 }
```

I am rendering the content in the following way...

```
...
...
<Text style={styles.normalText}>{jsonData.get(item.value)}</Text>
...
...
```

Where styles.normalText is...

```
normalText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    lineHeight: 21,
    fontWeight: '400',
    paddingBottom: 24,
},
```

Now I want only "this part" words from value1 of json to be bold. I don't have any clue how to achieve that. I don't want to use InnerHTML since it is vulnerable to XSS injection. But I want to do something like defining my own custom style like...

```
boldText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    lineHeight: 21,
    fontWeight: '700',
    paddingBottom: 24,
},
```

and use `<boldText> </boldText>` tag in the json file wherever I want bold text. Is this possible?

Comment: InnerHTML is only vulnerable to XSS injection if data is input by user. Is it true in your case?

Comment: No. It's a static text loaded on the page. No input is taken from the user.

Comment: Then you can use innerHTML because if the text is static then user can not modify it or inject any malicious data.